# Adding a MVC 4 controller using entity framework 5 database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to configure an MVC 4 application using EF 5 against the System.Web.Providers Membership DB.  The ADO.NET Entity Data Model appears correct.  The classes generated by the EF 5.x code generator look ok, but do not have a [Key] attribute.  When I try to create a User Controller, I get the following error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Citrius.Admin.User'. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

```
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Membership' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Profile' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Memberships' is based on type 'Membership' that has no keys defined.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Profiles' is based on type 'Profile' that has no keys defined.
```

I thought I saw a walkthrough of this, using these versions, but cannot find it.  I've tried to find a solution but all the examples are of previous versions.

Am I too far out on the bleeding edge??  Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: There is no meaningful difference between MVC4 and EF5 and MVC3 and EF4.x with what you are doing.  You're not doing anything that is specific to either of the newer versions.  One does not use "Key" for database first.  I think your problem is more likely related to the fact you are naming your entities the same name as the Membership and Profile classes, and getting conflicts.  In any event, it's impossible to tell what your problem is without more information about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you assign the Key manually?

Go into each one and add [Key] above the field that should be the Key.

That should get rid of these errors.